# xinit Clutter application not working

Tags: xorg, clutter

I've built a simple test app with clutter: A stage with two ClutterText actors to display two words. It works OK when I run it from within gnome but running it from the tty (not gnome-terminal or xterm) with `xinit my_app_binary` I get an error:

```
failed to create drawable
Unable to initialize Clutter: Unable to select the newly created GLX context
Window manager error: Unable to initialize Clutter
```

If I run `xinit gnome-terminal` from the same tty everything works, gnome-terminal shows up in a black screen. That's the same I want to do with my app.
Is there anything I can do to overcome this error?

All the above are tested in Linux Mint 12. After normal boot I switch to a tty (ALT-F1) and stop lightdm (sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop).

Thanks!

EDIT: running as root everything works, so the question is: how to run it as a regular user?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set the DISPLAY-var - add it in front of your command

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 /path/to/myapp
```

Sometimes this is an access-rights problem - the app should be started with the user who started the X-server

```
su user-started-x -c 'DISPLAY=:0.0 /path/to/myapp'
```